# Jeu de mots sur « grenapêche »

Tags: alimentation, jeux-de-mots

There is [an herbal tea](http://celestialseasonings.ca/fr/produits/tisane/grenapeche/) called "Country Peach Passion" in English and "Grenapêche" en français.

Here's the list of ingredients in French:

> Écorce d’orange, baies d’églantier, aubépine, camomille, arômes naturels (contient de la lécithine de soja et des sulfites), feuilles de mûrier, hibiscus, pêches, acide citrique, paprika. Contient du soja et des sulfites.

Where did they get the *grena-* part? One guess is *grenade*/*grenadier*, but that doesn't figure in the list above. I suppose it could be among the other « arômes naturels », but to go from an anonymous flavour to part of the name of the tea is quite a leap. Naturally, I also rule out *grenaille*, *grenadine*, *grenouille*, *grenat*.

My best alternative theory so far is *grenier*, hinting at "country" in the sense of "all that is harvested & stored in the countryside", and the *a-* is just euphonic. But I thought I'd post it here in case anyone can spot a more compelling justification.

Comment: What colour is it? I'm asking because then one shouldn't rule out grenadine. When one evokes [grenadine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirop_de_grenadine) it's not the fruit grenade that comes to mind to most people but the colour and the fact that is it a reddish fruity kind of drink. In France the ingredients of the regular (as opposed to the luxury one) grenadine are  *framboises, cassis, groseilles, sureau, fraises, citron*. And even if this *grenapêche* is not of a reddish colour it might be to evoke the name of grenadine that is generally appealing to children. My 2 cents.

Comment: @None Oh, very interesting! Not sure what colour it is, but if it's at all peach-y, I suspect it'd come out about that reddish colour.

Comment: I don't think there can be any intention of a "jeu de mots" in the coining of that term; (Jeu de mots. Procédé linguistique se fondant sur la ressemblance phonique des mots indépendamment de leur graphie et visant à amuser l'auditoire par l'équivoque qu'il engendre. ) There is probably nothing more intended than  giving the product a name as descriptive  as possible ; in my opinion, the name of a  would be serious product can't be chosen  for catering to people's taste for more or less gratuitous double meanings.

Comment: It is obviously a *jeu de mot*. The name might also be based on *[grenat](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grenat)* which is the name of a color, from the red stone named *grenat* too. There is still a link with *grenadine* because the stone got also its name from the [grenade](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/grenade).

Comment: @jlliagre Since it's obvious to everyone but a certain user that it's a jeu de mot, I chose not to respond lest the comment thread be derailed as usual. :p Interesting note on *grenat*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my mind the fact that the name *Grenapêche*® would be derived from *grenadine* shouldn't be ruled out.

1- **Ingredients**
The fact that there is no *grenadine* (pomegranate) in the list of ingredients doesn't stand. *Grenadine* is a soft drink made of grenadine syrup diluted in water. It's long since grenadine syrup doesn't contain the slightest scrap of pomegranate<sup>1</sup>, except for some very expensive luxury brands or the do-it-yourself product. If any fruit used at all<sup>2</sup> in the off the shelf product they are  :  *framboises* (raspberries), *cassis* (blackcurants), *groseilles* (redcurrants), *sureau* (elderberries), *fraises* (strawberries), *citron* (lemon), and some grenadine syrups and use artificial food colouring as well.

So if we look at this *Grenapêche*® drink nothing in its ingredients prevents it from referring to grenadine, and on top of that it's got peaches.
Hence the play on words: *grenadine + pêche → grenapêche*.

2 - **Colour**
Grenapêche® is of a ["slightly cloudy orange colour"](https://onemoresteep.com/2019/11/20/celestial-seasoningss-country-peach-passion/) which is given by the paprika in it, and this is consistent with the colour of grenadine that can vary from [dark red to a light pinkish colour](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dilution-grenadine.jpg?uselang=fr).

3 -  **Hinting at "country"**
We are now going to look into the part where the OP is trying to find a trace of "country style" in the French denomination of the product. To my mind "country style" could refer to something that is old fashioned, i.e. that is not modern/contemporary, and makes us think of our childhood. And that's exactly what grenadine does to someone who grew up in France in the middle of the previous century and for whom *sirop de grenadine* is their *[madeleine de Proust](https://www.thelocal.fr/20190814/french-expression-of-the-day-madeleine-de-proust/)*.

Quoting [from a 2019 magazine](https://www.femmeactuelle.fr/cuisine/guides-cuisine/tout-savoir-sur-la-grenadine-2089777):

> Elle nous met l’eau à la bouche. Pause écarlate, sirotée entre deux parties de chat perché, **la grenadine a ce goût de l’enfance**<sup>3</sup>. Si nos souvenirs sont authentiques, la boisson n’a de grenade que le nom. Dans le sirop, il n’y a, en effet, aucune trace de cette grosse baie rose à pulpe ...

4- **Subsidiary remark**
The Canadian branch of this company seems to like playing on words when transposing the name of their products into French: their *Sleepytime tea*® becomes *Tranquillithé*® (*tranquillité* decomposed as *tranquille+thé*). Not up to me to judge...

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> "... l’une des plus belles arnaques de l’industrie agro-alimentaire de ces dernières années". [Comment faire du sirop de grenadine maison](https://cocktailmolotov.org/sirops/comment-faire-sirop-grenadine/)</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup>  According to [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenadine) in the US one can find grenadine without a single name of fruit in the list of ingredients.</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> My emphasis.</sup>

Comment: Very nice — I think you've convincingly reverse-engineered some likely reasons the translation was approved in the first place!